# dialogflow :: detect intent and switch context at the same time

Tags: python, dialogflow-es, google-apis-explorer

Is there any way to switch or change context while detecting intent in dialogflow?

N.B: my requirement is such a way that I can't use webhook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whereas we can't switch context while detecting intent,but we can set the context at design time and runtime.

I have ended up setting context at runtime and it served my purpose.

For convenience you can check the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/contexts-manage)

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible. If you are using Dialogflow without code, setting context is tied to the event that Dialogflow detects.

If by "can't use a webhook" you only mean that you can't host a server, then you could also try the [inline editor](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/fulfillment-inline-editor) to handle the setting of context once an intent is detected.

Comment: i have ended up setting context at runtime and now dialogflow inline editor is paid couldn't experiment there.